# How to delay .live() until UI has updated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I am using jQuery and jQuery UI and i am trying to read a checkbox state through the addition of the "aria-pressed" property that jQuery UI Button toggle between false and true.

```
$('.slideButton').live('click', function() {

alert($(this).attr('aria-pressed'));

});
```

This code however seems to read the aria-pressed before jQuery UI has updated aria-pressed. So i unreliable values. Can i schedule it to execute after the UI has updated or can i make it wait?

[Live example here!](http://jonasbengtson.se/projects/dh/admin/)

Comment: Why are you trying to read checkbox state via `aria-pressed`?

Comment: I am trying to fetch which state the checkbox is in. I don't know any other way :(

Comment: Might want to look at the [jQuery :checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you add a listener to the actual checkbox behind the label or span?

```
$("#days_list li div div div input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
     alert("Someone just clicked checkbox with id"+$(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This should work since, once you click the label, you change the value in the checkbox.

---

Alright, I've composed a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/S5NEf/4/) for you that demonstrates the general idea of how it works, and how you retrieve the status of the checkbox.

```
$("#checkbox_container input").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) alert("Checked!");
    else alert("Unchecked!");
});
```

In your case, since the checkbox is added dynamically by JQuery you have to use the live event, but it is basically the same thing

```
$("#checkbox_container input").live("changed"....
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/S5NEf/8/) with some additional scripting and checking, mostly for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: Doesn't seem so due to it being AJAX loaded content. But i can use live as a change event?

Comment: It works with live('changed'.... but how can i know which state the button has after it's been clicked?

Comment: To check which state it has, you use `$(this).attr("checked")` which can either return, 'undefined' or 'checked'. I updated the post with a live example.

Comment: `$(this).is(':checked')` seems like a bit more intuitive way of determining the state of a checkbox.

Comment: @ChrisShouts I suppose it is. I'll update the answer, thanks.

Comment: It seems that the big problem is that i use jQuery UI Buttons, the checked isn't checked (apparently?). But you solved it without jQuery UI buttons so i will change my buttons to your style instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback to execute the `alert($(this).attr('aria-pressed'));` after the toggle has completed.

```
$('.slidebutton').toggle(1000, function(){

    alert($(this).attr('aria-pressed'));
});
```

I'm not too sure if your using `.toggle()` or not but you would need to use a callback either way to ensure sequential execution.

Comment: I am adding all buttons dynamically through an AJAX call so it doesn't seem to work. That's why i used live() in the first place (at least i think i have to use live() ). Can i use toggle as a live() event?